# How to convert JSON log to non JSON flat log using fluent bit?

Tags: logging, fluentd, fluent-bit

I have an application log file, where each line is a JSON. A line looks like below.

```
{"timestamp":"2023-04-25T03:40:03.180Z","level":"DEBUG","message":"\"some log message\"","thread":"main_thread","logger":"com.my.package.SomeClass","context":"default","host":"some-host"}
```

I need to upload it to s3 using fluent bit, but log lines should be non JSON. A line should look like below.

```
2023-04-25T03:40:03.180Z [main_thread] DEBUG com.my.package.SomeClass - some log message
```

Is it possible to achieve this with fluent bit?